# Послать Post запрос сервису используя сертификат

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, x509certificate, криптография

Я делаю автоматическую загрузку файлов с сервиса. Часть файлов можно скачать используя публичное `API`, часть используя приватное `API`. Приватное `API` хочет от меня использование сертификатов.На сайте разработчика сайта есть софт который делает те же манипуляции, но автоматического скачивания нет. И этот софт требует в настройках указать **слепок** сертификата(34.10-2012) который идет вместе с ним. Так же он требует для приватных функций указать персональный сертификат который у меня есть.

В своей программе я получаю персональный сертификат и отправляю запрос, но сервис выдает ошибку. *Я так понимаю надо еще как то указать слепок корневого сертификата* как это требует их софт. Т.е клиент должен при отправке использовать 2 сертификата. Не могу разобраться. Ранее не использовал сертификаты. Поэтому испытываю затруднения

```
        public async Task CallWebService()
    {
        var _url = "http://xxxxxx.ru:7081/PersonalApi/PersonalApiService.svc/ByCertificate";
        var _action =  "http://xxxxx.ru/soft/dssi/XXXX/XXX/Web/Api/PersonalApi/IPersonalApiService/TestAuthentication";

        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);

        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509CertificateCollection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "2C1EC4D41005000071B0", false);
        webRequest.ClientCertificates = certs;
        InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
        try
        {
            var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            string soapResult;
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Console.Write(soapResult);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gregor, если вам ещё актуально:

1. нужно добавить в ваше хранилище сертификатов корневой сертификат сервиса,
2. при подготовке запроса извлечь его и
3. добавить в клиентские сертификаты запроса.

```
    X509CertificateCollection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "2C1EC4D41005000071B0", false);
    // Get the issuer certificate
    X509CertificateCollection issuer = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "<issuer_certificate_number>", false);
    // Add it to the certificate collection
    certs.AddRange(issuer);
    webRequest.ClientCertificates = certs;
```

Comment: Да, я так и сделал. Спасибо